# Android: How is the row id assigned to a ListView

Tags: android, listview, row

I want to show different message when tapping on a listview item, could anyone help me understand how I can explicitly bind a specific column (e.x., room_id) to the list view so that the id in the onItemClick takes the room_id.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {

        }
    });
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to your adapter (that you pass to listView.setAdapter() )
You have to implement these methods (of your adapter) correctly.

```
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
```

And you will be able to get current id directly OR your object (and its id if its a property)

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
   @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position,long id)     {
       ListView lv = (ListView) parent;
       YOUR_OBJECT yourItem = (YOUR_OBJECT) parent.getSelectedItem();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! So is getItemId() always supposed to return the row Id for the list view?

Comment: Not always.. Actually it depends of your implementation as I told you

Comment: so getItemId() will be passed in as the id parameter for onItemClick(), correct?

Comment: I think I get that. Thank you very much azerto00!

Answer (score 1):

in list view, you have to pass list of objects as it's arguments.

```
listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
adapter = new YourCustomeAdapter(this, rowItems);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here rowItems is your list of objects.

in the setOnItemClickListener method, you will obtain each object of the rowItem list by using the position.

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 
 @Override 
   public void   onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position,long id) {

  }
});
```

In my cases,int position and long id both gives the same value ie. if first item in list view is clicked, the value of position and id in OnItemClick() is 0 which ultimately gives you the index of the column room_id. So you can explicitly bind the specific column (e.x., room_id) to the list view so that the id in the onItemClick() takes the room_id.